# Best way to create a scrollable list that dynamically grows

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-desktop

I have a flutter web app (which may become a desktop app in the future) that contains a dialog box. The dialog allows the user to edit the properties of a model object that contains a list of elements. The user should be able to edit the list by adding or deleting elements to the list. So the dialog contents are of variable height -- it depends on the number of elements in the list.

I am having trouble creating a layout that dynamically resizes appropriately. What I want is for the dialog to grow as items are added to the list, up to the maximum size that would fit on the device's screen. If the contents grow larger than this, the elements in the list should be scrollable.

I've attached two screenshots of what I have working at the moment; the first has a list with only two items, which is easily displayed. The second is the same dialog with many items showing the overflow.

[image: Dialog with Two Items]

[image: Dialog with Many Items]

Here is the code for the Dialog:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
          child: const Text('CANCEL'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: const Text('OK'),
          onPressed: () =>
              Navigator.of(context).pop<Modifier>(_createModifier()),
        ),
      ],
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text('Damage Editor'),
          Divider(),
          columnSpacer,
          DiceSpinner(
            onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _dice = value),
            initialValue: _dice,
            textFieldWidth: 90.0,
          ),
          columnSpacer,
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            child: DropdownButton<DamageType>(
              underline: Container(),
              value: _type,
              items: _damageTypeItems(),
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _type = value),
            ),
          ),
          columnSpacer,
          SwitchListTile(
            value: _direct,
            onChanged: (state) => setState(() => _direct = state),
            title: Text(_direct ? 'Internal (Direct)' : 'External (Indirect)'),
          ),
          if (!_direct) ...<Widget>[
            columnSpacer,
            CheckboxListTile(
              value: _explosive,
              onChanged: (state) => setState(() => _explosive = state),
              title: Text('Explosive'),
            ),
          ],
          columnSpacer,
          DynamicListHeader(
            title: 'Enhancements/Limitations',
            onPressed: () => setState(() =>
                _modifiers.add(TraitModifier(name: 'Undefined', percent: 0))),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: _enhancementList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _enhancementList() {
    var list = <Widget>[];
    _modifiers.forEach(
      (element) {
        if (_modifiers.length > 0) list.add(columnSpacer);
        list.add(_EnhancerEditor(element, index: _modifiers.indexOf(element),
            onChanged: (index, enhancer) {
          _modifiers[index] = enhancer;
        }));
      },
    );
    return list;
  }


typedef TraitModifierCallback = void Function(int, TraitModifier);

class _EnhancerEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  _EnhancerEditor(this.enhancer, {this.onChanged, this.index});

  final TraitModifier enhancer;
  final TraitModifierCallback onChanged;
  final int index;

  @override
  __EnhancerEditorState createState() => __EnhancerEditorState();
}

class __EnhancerEditorState extends State<_EnhancerEditor> {
  TextEditingController _nameController;
  TextEditingController _percentController;
  bool _validInput = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _nameController = TextEditingController(text: widget.enhancer.name);
    _nameController.addListener(_onChanged);

    _percentController =
        TextEditingController(text: widget.enhancer.percent.toString());
    _percentController.addListener(_onChanged);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nameController.removeListener(_onChanged);
    _nameController.dispose();

    _percentController.removeListener(_onChanged);
    _percentController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onChanged() {
    String text = _percentController.text.trim();
    setState(() {
      int value = int.tryParse(text);
      _validInput = (value != null);

      if (_validInput) {
        widget.onChanged(widget.index,
            TraitModifier(name: _nameController.text, percent: value));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _nameController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enhancer/Limitation',
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          rowSmallSpacer,
          SizedBox(
            width: 80.0,
            child: TextField(
              controller: _percentController,
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true),
              inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9\-]'))
              ],
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                suffixText: '%',
                labelText: 'Pct',
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of you using `IntrinsicHeight` here?

Comment: Uh, it didn't work without it? I was getting an error that said something about the widget having an infinite height, or some such. Adding IntrinsicHeight removed that error.

Comment: Have you tried substituting in the `ListView` for the `Column` and also deleting the `IntrinsicHeight`? (Or replacing it with something else that specifies a deterministic height.)

Answer (score 0):

It may sound counterintuitive but you should have ListView within Column. You need both.

In dialog Column will deal with dialog size, and ListView will deal with scrolling within.

```
Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children:[
ListView(padding: EdgeInsets.all(0), 
            shrinkWrap: true, 
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
```

Ok, here you go ... Simple call of dialog ...

```
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showDialog(
                  useRootNavigator: false,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => Test(),
                );
              },
              child: Text('Suppper'),
            )
```

then code of dialog ... it is pretty straight forward ...
all controllers you can place in a map that you will deal with when you add new entries... both adding and removing is super easy ... let me know if further assitance is needed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget rowEntry(_nameController, _percentController) {
    return IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _nameController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enhancer/Limitation',
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 80.0,
            child: TextField(
              controller: _percentController,
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true),
              inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9\-]'))],
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                suffixText: '%',
                labelText: 'Pct',
                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  addEntry() async {
    entries.add('new value');
    setState(() {});
  }

  List entries = [];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        width: 300,
        child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: [
          Text('here you will put all that is above (+)'),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text('Exhancements/Limitations'),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    addEntry();
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemCount: entries == null ? 0 : (entries.length),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return rowEntry(null, null);
              }),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: result of the above code]

Comment: Replacing the SingleChildScrollView with ListView does not work, it throws a rendering exception.

Comment: which exception you are getting? hasSize?

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

Comment: If you have `shrinkWrap: true` on the `ListView`, the `Column` becomes redundant.

Comment: It does not always work well with ```shrinkWrap:true``` only, depends what you have around ListView, etc. etc. Was fighting with this numerous times, especially in Dialog.

Comment: @dGoran Is this code tested? I did not copy it directly, but I structured my code to match yours and I am still getting the assertion: 
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

Comment: @beek geek Yap, that code was written and run before posting here... Just added image there.